# How do I watch SopCast channels?

Tags: tv

How to watch Sopcast channels from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here

http://code.google.com/p/sopcast-player/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 1):

I installed it via [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) and once started, I play the content via VLC (Media > Open Network Stream... > http://localhost:8902).

You maybe need to click the "Open in external player" button before you can open the stream in VLC (sorry, I don't remember):

[image]